# Update columns when they're not null and insert when they are null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases, `testFrom` and `testTo`.  Their purpose is to take the values of select columns from `testFrom` and overwrite the those same columns in `testTo`.  Both databases are dealing with a table of the same name, `dbo.People`.  These two databases don't have the same number of record so the transfer **will not** be 1:1.  Because of this I am working on a query that updates the values of the rows that exist and inserting the remaining data for those that don't.

Currently my update works but the insert will add new rows with null values instead of the values from `testFrom`.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, could it be the join statement on my insert?

```
UPDATE to_p
    SET to_p.DottedID = from_p.DottedID, to_p.Name = from_p.Name, to_p.Colour = from_p.Colour, to_p.Food = from_p.Food
    FROM testFrom.dbo.people to_p left join testTo.dbo.People from_p on to_p.Name = from_p.Name
    WHERE from_p.Name IS NOT NULL;
INSERT INTO testTo.dbo.People (to_p.DottedID, to_p.Name, to_p.Colour, to_p.Food)
    SELECT from_p.DottedID, from_p.Name, from_p.Colour, from_p.Food
    FROM testFrom.dbo.people to_p left join testTo.dbo.People from_p on to_p.Name = from_p.Name
    WHERE from_p.Name IS NULL;
```

The output is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the columns from wrong table. change your `INSERT` statement like below

```
INSERT INTO testTo.dbo.People (DottedID, Name, Colour, Food)
    SELECT to_p.DottedID, to_p.Name, to_p.Colour, to_p.Food
    FROM testFrom.dbo.people to_p left join testTo.dbo.People from_p 
    on to_p.Name = from_p.Name
    WHERE from_p.Name IS NULL;
```

Comment: It says 0 rows affected when I execute after your recommended change

Comment: @BlueBarren, yes got it wrong. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: Yeah that more or less works thanks.  Now I just have every old entry still in there though

Comment: @BlueBarren, post a separate question saying what's you are trying to achieve after the insert with those old entries. if you fell you can post the link of new question here in comment.

Comment: I think it might be fine actually.  I cleared the receiving db and ran the query twice and it only updated once because it saw everything else existed already.  It was probably just some after math of testing before.